# For and if loops in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, average

After a few grades I enter done and it prints to minimum grade but not the average. Can someone plese help me fix this?

```
grades = []
print('Enter up to 100 grades')
  for i in range(1,100):
    number = input("Please Enter Grade/enter 'done' when finish: ")
    grades.append(number)
  if 'done' in grades:
    grades.remove('done')
    print('\n')
    print(grades)   
    print('Highest Grade: ',max(grades))      
    print('Minimum Grade:',min(grades))
    print('Average Grade: ',(sum(grades)/len(grades)))
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that the code is in a code block because it is very difficult to read as is. If you need help doing this see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
grades = []
print('Enter up to 100 grades')
    for i in range(1,100):
    number = input("Please Enter Grade/enter 'done' when finish: ")
    grades.append(number)
    if 'done' in grades:
        grades.remove('done')
        print('\n')
        print(grades) 
        grades = list(map(int, grades))
        print('Highest Grade: ',max(grades))      
        print('Minimum Grade:',min(grades))
        print('Average Grade: ',sum(grades)/len(grades))
```

You'll notice I changed the indentation a bit. Additionally, I added a line to convert the list of strings to a list of integers. I am not sure what (if any) error messages you were receiving but these changes addressed compile errors (indentation was cause) and data type errors (performing sum function on string).

I hope it helps!

Comment: the user is supposed to be able to input as many grades for the program to calculate the highest, minimum, and average grades. So I can't code the list in the program before hand.

Comment: I have updated my comment to provide you with code for dynamic input. As noted by Bruno, your biggest issue was using sum on your list of strings (grades). I modified as little as I could to maintain the code you provided while bringing it into a working state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code formatted:

```
grades = [] 
print('Enter up to 100 grades') 

for i in range(1,100): 
  number = input("Please Enter Grade/enter 'done' when finish: ") 
  grades.append(number) 

  if 'done' in grades: 
    grades.remove('done') 

print('\n') 
print(grades)
print('Highest Grade: ',max(grades))
print('Minimum Grade:', min(grades))
print('Average Grade: ',(sum(grades)/len(grades)))
```

You are storing the grades as strings, so the sum function crashes attempting to sum the elements in `grades`. You should convert your inputs to a number, but taking care of the `done` case.